# SpeechRecognitionEngine does not recognize the whole file

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I'm working with audiofiles (wav) and SpeechRecognitionEngine. The goal is to transcribe my wav files and I have implemented as

```
        var dictationGrammar = new DictationGrammar();

        var speechRecognitionEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
        speechRecognitionEngine.LoadGrammar(dictationGrammar);
        speechRecognitionEngine.BabbleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(999.0);
        speechRecognitionEngine.EndSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0);
        speechRecognitionEngine.EndSilenceTimeoutAmbiguous = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0);
        speechRecognitionEngine.SpeechRecognized += (s, e) => SpeechRecognized(s, e, audioPath.Replace("wav", "txt"));
        speechRecognitionEngine.SetInputToWaveFile(audioPath);
        speechRecognitionEngine.Recognize();

    private static void SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e, string fileName)
    {
        string transcription = e.Result.Text;

        File.WriteAllText(fileName, transcription);
    }
```

SpeechRecognized fires once.

I'm using high/max values for the different timeouts, but it's not giving me the transcription of the whole file. The audiofile is 1 min 12 sec long, but I seem to only get the first 30 seconds.

Comment: Please share your method implementation `SpeechRecognized (s, e, audioPath.Replace("wav", "txt")`

Comment: @user2932057 added the code. It only fires once.

Comment: In the speech Recognized Event you are passing the same file name [Seem like it will replace the older one]. So, Instead of `File.WriteAllText` - Try appending to same file`File.AppendAllText(fileName, transcription);`